# org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter<S, T> give error: Null can not be a value of a non-null type

Tags: spring, kotlin

I try to implement Spring Converter, but I had got the error in unit testing:

```
Kotlin: Null can not be a value of a non-null type TodoItem
```

If I try to change convert method signature from

```
override fun convert(source: TodoItem): GetTodoItemDto?
```

to

```
override fun convert(source: TodoItem?): GetTodoItemDto?
```

that pass null to method I have other errors:

```
Error:(10, 1) Kotlin: Class 'TodoItemToGetTodoItemDto' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member @Nullable public abstract fun convert(p0: TodoItem): GetTodoItemDto? defined in org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter
Error:(14, 5) Kotlin: 'convert' overrides nothing
```

Code samples:

**TodoItemToGetTodoItemDto.kt**

```
package com.example.todo.converters

import com.example.todo.dtos.todo.GetTodoItemDto
import com.example.todo.model.TodoItem
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
class TodoItemToGetTodoItemDto : Converter<TodoItem?, GetTodoItemDto> {

    @Nullable
    @Synchronized
    override fun convert(source: TodoItem): GetTodoItemDto? {
        if(source == null){
            return null
        }

        return GetTodoItemDto(source.id, source.name, source.isComplete)
    }

}
```

**TodoItemToGetTodoItemDtoTest.kt**

```
package com.example.todo.converters

import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test

import org.junit.Assert.*


class TodoItemToGetTodoItemDtoTest {
    private lateinit var conveter : TodoItemToGetTodoItemDto

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        conveter = TodoItemToGetTodoItemDto()
    }

    @Test
    fun testNullObject(){
        assertNull(conveter.convert(null))
    }

}
```

**GetTodoItemDto.kt**

```
package com.example.todo.dtos.todo

data class GetTodoItemDto(val id: Long, val name: String, val isComplete: Boolean)
```

**TodoItem.kt**

```
package com.example.todo.model

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.Id

@Entity
data class TodoItem @JsonCreator constructor(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
        var id: Long,
        var name: String,
        var isComplete: Boolean){
    constructor(): this(0, "", false)
    constructor(name:String) : this(0, name, false)
}
```

Could you explain to me how it is possible to implement using Kotlin? May be I do something wrong using Kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think what you're trying to do is valid. If you look at the `Converter.convert` JavaDocs you'll see that the `source` argument into the `convert` function has this:

> @param source the source object to convert, which must be an instance
>   of {@code S} (**never {@code null}**)

So it explicitly says that you can never pass `null` into the `convert` function.

Conversely, what the `convert` function returns can be null:

> @return the converted object, which must be an instance of {@code T}
>   (**potentially {@code null}**)

The `convert` method in the Java code is annotated with `@Nullable` and the JavaDocs on that say:

> ...used by Kotlin to infer nullability of Spring API.

So that's how Kotlin is deciding whether the parameter can be null (in this case the parameter can't, but the return value can).